# reversing every second set of 4 characters

Tags: java, string, math, split, reverse

I have started to write a code that would reverse every second set of 4 characters. eg. 1234567890987654. The result would be displayed as ("1234" "8765" "9098" "4567"). This would then be multiplied as in "1234" * "8765" * "9098" * "4567".
this code doesn't work and I would like some help.

My code currently is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "1234567890987654";
    System.out.println(result);

public static int reverse(String a) {
    String newa = "";
    String str = a;
    char ch;
    String[] array = str.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
    a = "array[]";

    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length() ; i=i+2) {
        ch = a.charAt(i);
        newa = ch + newa;
        //System.out.println(newcardNum);
    }

    return newa;
}
```

Thanks in adavance

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Every one of those lines looks like it comes from a different program... we've got half a `main` that doesn't call reverse. `reverse` copies it's parameter and the replaces it  - somewhere along the line it picks up a `cardNum` and uses that for something...

Comment: Not sure if this is a joke or not. Like what is this `a= "array[]";`?

Comment: woops cardNum is from a different program i wrote

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by creating a proper test framework (at least a toy testing framework) -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "1234567890987654";
    String expected = "1234" + "8765" + "9098" + "4567";
    String result = reverse(input);
    if (result.equals(expected)) {
        System.out.println("result matches expected result");
    } else {
        System.out.println("result does not match expected result");
    }
    System.out.printf("input='%s', result = '%s'%n", input, result);
}
```

Now we can tell when the result we receive matches our expected result, and what the input and output String(s) are.

Next, we need to fix your reversing algorithm. You want to get 4 character then reverse 4 characters, so each iteration is 8 characters. Something like,

```
public static String reverse(String a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i += 8) { // <-- increment by 8.
        sb.append(a.substring(i, i + 4)); // <-- pass 1,4
        // get characters 4 to 8 
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(a.substring(i + 4, i + 8));
        // reverse and append
        sb.append(sb2.reverse().toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Output is

```
result matches expected result
input='1234567890987654', result = '1234876590984567'
```

**Edit** Based on your comments below (and edited question), add something like this to `main`

```
String[] arr = new String[4];

long calc = 1; // <-- int would overflow
for (int count = 0, i = 0; i < result.length(); count++, i += 4) {
    arr[count] = result.substring(i, i + 4);
    calc *= Integer.parseInt(arr[count]);
}
System.out.printf("Array = %s, multiplication = %d%n", Arrays.toString(arr), calc);
```

And now the output is

```
result matches expected result
input='1234567890987654', result = '1234876590984567'
Array = [1234, 8765, 9098, 4567], multiplication = 449411337361660
```

Comment: thanks so if I want to use the reversed string in the "public static String reverse(String a) {", do i make newA = to sb?

Comment: @doublepainpain Do you mean convert it from a `String` to an `int`? Use `Integer.parseInt(String)`. You can also use `Integer.toString(int)` to convert an `int` to a `String`.

Comment: I want to multiply "1234" * "8765" * "9098" * "4567" to create a number that would be use in another part of the program.

Comment: Then why does your question say *The result would be displayed as ("1234" "8765" "9098" "4567")*?

Comment: Thats a different part of the program. I'm not sure what my newA should equal to in your code. If you want I can change my question

Comment: @doublepainpain I removed `newa` because it doesn't work in your code. It seemed like it was intended to build the `String` that I return from `sb`.

Comment: I've tried the code and it works very well. One question can the multiplication be done in the revere section instead of the main. i would like to keep my main for only the entering of strings. Thanks